# Spark CSV Dataframe Load ,File not found

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe

How to catch exception , if my file is not found in given location in spark csv read?

```
try {
    val df = sqlCxt.read.format("csv")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .load("C:/Users/swapnil.shirke/Downloads/dataset/u.item");

}
catch {

case ex: FileNotFoundException => {
println(" file missing exception")
}
case ex: Exception => ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

given try catch condition not worked.

Comment: have you checked in your executor logs whether that message is printed or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scala, if the file path is not correct then the exception is `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: ....` so the correct way is

```
try {
  val df = sqlCxt.read.format("csv")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .load("/Users/swapnil.shirke/Downloads/dataset/u.item");

}
catch {
  case ex: AnalysisException => {
    println(" file missing exception")
  }
  case ex: Exception => ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

I hope the answer is helpful